# How to bind SQL query and GetMapping

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Framework. I want to filter a MySQL table user_table with queries (show certain data with a REST API). I created a Spring Boot project with a repository like this:

```java
import java.util.List;

public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM userdb.user_table u WHERE u.name='Jean'", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<User> user_jean(String name);
}
```

My query in MySQL works, so I think my map in my controller has a problem.

My controller is like this:

```java
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @GetMapping(value = "/user/name")
    public List<User> userList (@RequestParam String name) {
        return userRepo.user_jean(name);
   }
}
```

My web page shows a 400 Error Bad Request. I tried a lot of things but it doesn't work. How can I bind correctly a query with a controller? I want my table shows only user with name = Jean.

Someone has an idea?

Comment: what is the request url you are using to call this controller?

Comment: How your request looks loke?

Comment: BTW: Do not use `_` in method names. By conventions you should use camleCase names

Comment: thanks for answering. I use http://localhost:8080/user/name is that not correct ?

Comment: Ok thanks for the _ tips !

Comment: it should be  `localhost:8080/user/name?name=Jean`

Comment: Thanks, I tried but I have Internal Server Error

Comment: can you post the whole stack trace.

Comment: No not from postman...you will find the exception stack trace in the spring boot application.

Comment: Sorry, the trace is : nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause

Comment: [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL

Answer (score 1):

just change your controller to this:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;

@GetMapping(value = "/user/{name}")
public List<User> userList (@PathVariable String name) {
    return userRepo.user_jean(name);}}
```

and change your repo to this :

```
import java.util.List;
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM userdb.user_table u WHERE u.name=:name", nativeQuery = true)
public List<User> user_jean(@Param("name") String name);}
```

Comment: In this case the request url should be `http://localhost:8080/user/Jean`

Comment: yes, you should pass variable name in  the path

Comment: Thanks to everyone a lot, but 500 Internal Error persist... Maybe some authorization on mysql or something like that

Comment: Works ! Forgot a little thing, thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you give us your answer please